# Is posting SQL code in forums a bad idea?

Tags: sql, security

Is there any risk in posting SQL code from my company in these forums, or in any forums for that matter?

Specifically I am referring to examples of SQL queries. These queries obviously show joins to tables and different fields in my database tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The risk is pretty low, if:

- you do not publish company's name or web address
- there are no SQL injection waiting to be exploited in that SQL of yours
- server itself is secure and pached
- you do not publish connection credentials with your snippet

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to obscure relevant names, etc. Think of a good analogy and replace names with that. I don't think people care too much to try and "find you out". We're much more interested in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it doesn't show proprietary information, SQL is SQL. I would always recommend sharing "fake" information for example data.

Answer (score 1):

Only the connection information (username, password, IP, etc) is sensitive - without that information:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM EMPLOYEES e
```

...is quite safe. Neither I nor anyone else can delete anything in your tables.

I don't recommend abstracting things too much when posting questions - some details can make all the difference to determine the issue you're encountering.